# 14.04 Headphones do not appear as an output device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, 14.04

I installed 14.04 yesterday. I always leave my headphones and speakers plugged in together, so I know I have them in the right ports.

Sound came though the speakers just fine, but nothing came through the headphones. After opening System Settings>>Sound, I found only two output devices listed: Digital Output (S/PDIF) and Analog Output. Selecting Analog Output goes through the speakers, and the other option does not give me any sound.

When I had Windows 7 installed I used the RealTek Audio Manager. I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to Ubuntu so I probably just did something stupid. Thanks.

**Headphones work when plugged into the port that the speakers were using.

Answer (score 0):

open terminam  , type  `alsamixer` , then navigate to HP/speakers ,press <kbd>M</kbd> on Keyboard (Un Muting) ,

Now remove audio jack and insert again, It should work as expected,

Its bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1267675

By default CA0132 has the HP/Speaker and HP/Speaker Auto Detect muted. Unmuting them by going into alsamixer and pressing <kbd>M</kbd> on their controls unmutes them and sound works.'

Good Luck